# Difference between textbox text added by binding and added by code in windows form C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, windows-forms-designer

I have a `TextBox` with a data binding, which I later update the text on via the `combobox_selectedindexchanged()` event of `ComboBox`.

My problem is that the data gets changed on this `combobox_selectedindexchanged()` event but when i *click* on the `TextBox` data gets disappeared.

Comment: could you please post relavent code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are updating the TextBox.Text property on a bound TextBox.

Don't do this !

If you need to update the text in that TextBox, update the underlying DataSource

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I created a project do whatever as you mentioned above. The `TextBox`'s Text changed into "Foo" after `comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged` event, then when I click on the `TextBox`, it is still there. Here's my code.

```
private Foo _foo;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _foo = new Foo();
    txtName.DataBindings.Add("Text", _foo, "Name");
}

private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtName.Text = "Foo";
}
```

Does you change the `TextBox`'s Text elsewhere? Maybe you should post your code here, so we can see what the matter is.

Comment: I binded textbox to Datasource, so when i click on textbox it takes value from that Datasource,. so now i update Datasource in combobox_selectedindexchanged event, and now its working........